# Easiest way to configure nginx to run CGI Perl and Python for few scripts that under very low use?

Tags: python, perl, nginx, amazon-web-services

I am looking for a simple nginx setup that runs Perl and Python scripts that are under very low load (99% of time a single user browsing them and no mode than 100 request/day).

Because the server is running on a AWS under a micro instance I am looking for something that has a very low memory footprint.

Update: I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 on it and after installing `nginx` which does not contain the embedded perl module, I installed `nginx-extras` which is supposed to contain it. Still I have no idea how to enable it, also strage it did not complain about the nginx package.

Comment: Are the scripts for WSGI/PSGI or CGI?

Answer (score 0):

nginx does not support (by design) CGIs.
You need an application server for managing them:

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/CGI

(it is pretty advanced so be prepared for some study, but you should be able to reach your objective)